# Optimise huge Postgres table for fast read

Tags: postgresql, performance, partitioning

I'm about to create a Postgres table with 1.5 billion rows. The table will just have a single TEXT column.

The table is effectively a blacklist. When a user of my software saves certain data, this table is looked-up to make sure the value they're saving doesn't exist in it.

What can I do to optimise Postgres or that table to make that "read" as fast as possible? The table will only ever be written to approximately once a year.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add a second column which will hold a hash of the text value.  Create the index on the hash.  Even if there is a hash collision there will be only a few rows to read and perform a full comparison on the text vlaues.

Comment: You can leave the extra column and create a functional index: CREATE INDEX foo ON t1((md5(c1)); Use WHERE md5(c1) = md5('content') in your select and you'll be fine. Check EXPLAIN

Comment: hashing rung a bell, but I had to go check **how** it made things faster. [This explanation helped](http://forums.udacity.com/answer_link/50164/#cs101). Is my understanding right... that I'd want to hash with MD5 so there **are** collisions, which is indexed, so the number of places to "look" for the data is actually far smaller than just indexing the column with the raw data in it. Right?

Comment: Yes - by hashing you can efficiently find a small number of text values to compare fully.

Comment: Using md5 will result in an index that is, in practice, unique. You cannot constrain it to be unique because you might find a hash collision. It's more likely than you think due to the birthday paradox - still quite unlikely, but possible. In practice though, the md5 will uniquely identify a value, so an index lookup for it will find just the page containing that value.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, to get the read-speed I needed I ended-up taking a different approach (although date I say it on a database Q&A site!).

Instead of using a database table to store the data, I created a text file with one line per value, sorted alphabetically.

Whenever I need to query to see whether a given value exists, I use a [binary search](https://study.cs50.net/binary_search) approach. I haven't done any performance metrics other than observation. It was clear this way was faster for what I needed.

Comment: Which is essentially the same thing as creating the index on the MD5 sum suggested by Frank. A lookup on an index _is_ a binary search as well

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh ok fair enough. I didn't realise that! Is there a link or somewhere that explains this for indexes in postgres? I've primarily only worked with other databases that take a different approach and always wondered how postgres did it but couldn't really find anything.

Comment: Essentially all DBMS use a some kind of a tree to represent an index ("B-Tree" - balanced trees). I'm not aware of any DBMS that does this differently (for standard indexes). Postgres' indexes are explained in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes.html